# Does converting a string to a float lose precision?

Tags: go

## Problem

When converting a `string` to a `float64`, the fractional part of the `float64` loses a significant amount of numbers.

## Code

```
origVal := "0.00000628"
convVal, err := strconv.ParseFloat(origVal, 64)
if err == nil {
    fmt.Printf("Original value: %s\nConverted value: %f\n", origVal, convVal)
}
```

Outputs:

```
Original value: 0.00000628
Converted value: 0.000006
```

The code is available on the Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/a8fH_JGug7l

## Context

I am pulling data from an API. This API stringifies floating point numbers. I convert these stringified numbers to floats because I want to do some basic arithmetics on them.
I am fairly new to Go, so my apologies if the answer is straightforward.

Comment: Does `Printf` in Go automatically display a fixed number of decimals? Is it possible to print more?

Comment: @usr2564301 That is it! Thanks for the fast reply.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was not that the string was not correctly converted, but that `Printf` does, by default, not output the complete fractional part if it is long.
The following code prints the same as the original code but with 10 numbers after the decimal point:

```
origVal := "0.00000628"
convVal, err := strconv.ParseFloat(origVal, 64)
if err == nil && err2 ==nil {
    fmt.Printf("Original value: %s\nConverted value: %.10f\n", origVal, convVal)
}
```

Thanks to @usr2564301 for the quick reply!

Comment: Probably you do already know it, but it maybe useful to remember that not all decimal numbers keep their representation in floating point. For example 100.100 printed with 15 decimal digits would give "100.099999999999994", or 100.499 would give 100.498999999999995